# Excel Gantt chart show 0 duration as milestone (plot 0 values as a point)

Tags: excel, charts, gantt-chart

It was really difficult to search for an answer to this because I find it hard to even phrase the question.  The short version of the question is this.

How do I plot zeros on a bar chart?

The use-case is I'm using Excel for a gantt chart. Start date gives the bar a home and the duration gives the bar a height. Plotted on a horizontal bar chart, this looks like a gantt chart. (I didn't invent the technique)

The problem is, I would like to plot milestones as well, where items with a duration of 0 would be a milestone.

Any thoughts?

Comment: My thought is use MS project.  use a custom combo to combine bars with a line graph.  turn the line of the line graph off just to plot points. you can even put the line chart on the secondary axis.  The problem is, in my version of excel, that combination only works in the vertical direction.  my quick fix to that is turn the page or monitor sideways when you need to look at it.

Comment: I don't have MS Project. I have MS Excel.

Comment: Everything after MSProject in my comment is for excel.  having said that I have thought in the past how I would incorporate a gantt chart into excel.  I originally dropped the concept due to column limitations and excel not being able to deal with more than 370 columns or so at the time.  It can now.  Instead of making a graph for your gantt chart, turn the spreadsheet itself into your gantt chart.  Set up Columns A through D or so as you ID number, taks name, start date, end date, etc.  Turn your row 1 into a header row, turn row 2 into the dates.

Comment: size your date columns so they look roughly square.  use conditional formatting to colour the date cells for a task based on > start date and < end date.  put  in a conditional check for start date= end date or milestone cell=y or the like and use a different colour coding, or set the font to match background colour for all other case except mile stones and then for miles stones make it black or the like.  Then have a symbol or peice of text in each date cell.